# Inheritance and Interface design improvement

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

so I have the following design:

for the models:

```
public class ParentTicket{
  protected ticketAttribute1
  protected ticketAttribute2
  protected ticketAttribute3

  //getters and setters here
}

public class ChildTicket1 extends ParentTicket{
  private childTicket1Attr1
  private childTicket1Attr2
  private childTicket1Attr3

  //getters and setters here
}

public class ChildTicket2 extends ParentTicket{
  private childTicket2Attr1
  private childTicket2Attr2
  private childTicket2Attr3

  //getters and setters here
}
```

For the ticket manager I have the following

```
public class TicketManager1{

   public ArrayList<ChildTicket1> getAlltickets(){ 
       //some implementation 
   }

   public void saveTicketToDB(ChildTicket1 ticket){ 
       //some implementation 
   }

}

public class TicketManager2{

   public ArrayList<ChildTicket2> getAlltickets(){ 
       //some implementation 
   }

   public void saveTicketToDB(ChildTicket2 ticket){ 
       //some implementation 
   }

}
```

I'm confused how I can improve the design, because as it is now it's going to be hard to add in more ticket managers/other types of tickets(I think so at least)

I tried to make an interface to be implemented by the ticket managers:

```
public interface IManageTickets{
  public Collection getAllTickets();
  public void saveTicketToDB(Ticket ticket);
  //some other methods
}
```

but I can't seem to implement it properly because the Ticket parameter not accepting the child tickets.

also, I'm going for MVC approach here so I'm not even sure if I should be making a ticket manager class and just add those methods to the model. I'm confused as to when you should add methods in a model or put them into their own class.

Answer (score 0):

create an interface for Tickets

```
public interface Tickets {

}
```

To have Different Tickets implement the interface

```
public class ChildTicket1 implemnets ParentTicket{


  //getters and setters here
}


public class ChildTicket2 implemnets ParentTicket{


  //getters and setters here
}
```

This is the ticket manager class pass the type as the interface type of Tickets

```
public class TicketManager{

       public ArrayList<Tickets> getAlltickets(){ 
           //some implementation 
       }

       public void saveTicketToDB(Tickets ticket){ 
           //some implementation 
       }

    }
```

if you want your attributes you can do

```
public class Tickets {
 protected ticketAttribute1
 protected ticketAttribute2
 protected ticketAttribute3
}

public class ChildTicket1 extends ParentTicket{


  //getters and setters here
}


public class ChildTicket2 extends ParentTicket{


  //getters and setters here
}





public class TicketManager{

       public ArrayList<Tickets> getAlltickets(){ 
           //some implementation 
       }

       public void saveTicketToDB(Tickets ticket){ 
           //some implementation 
       }

    }
```

this pattern is called a strategy pattern. If you want to learn more about how to design your applications more learn about design patterns.
this is a good reference find it and read it if you want http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do

Comment: you can put attributes in interfaces? I tried it but it gives me an error: Constant name does not follow naming conventions: ticketAttribute1

Comment: yeah don't put attributes in there

Comment: if you  need those attributes  you can have a Tickets class and extend from it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use generics in the ticket manager interface:

```
public interface TicketManager<T extends ParentTicket> {
    Collection<T> getTickets();
    void saveTicketToDb(T ticket);
}
```

The key here is to restrict the generic parameter `T` to be a subclass of `ParentTicket`.
An implementation of this for `ChildTicket1` would look like this:

```
public class TicketManager1 implements TicketManager<ChildTicket1> {
    @Override
    public Collection<ChildTicket1> getTickets() {
        // implementation goes here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveTicketToDb(ChildTicket1 ticket) {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

This approach can be particularly helpful if you need to build an API that gives access to all ticket types, e.g.:

```
public Collection<ParentTicket> getAllTickets() {
    List<TicketManager<? extends ParentTicket>> managers; // contains a list of all TicketManager implementations
    List<ParentTicket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TicketManager<? extends ParentTicket> manager : managers) {
        tickets.addAll(manager.getTickets());
    }
    return tickets;
}
```

Comment: for reference, what do you call the "implements TicketManager<ChildTicket1>" and "TicketManager<T extends ParentTicket>" if it's actually called any? I implemented this and it works but I want to look into this more since this is my first time seeing it.

Comment: `interface TicketManager<T extends ParentTicket>` is a _generic_ interface, `T` is called a _Type Variable_. When implementing this interface, you have the option to "assign" the type variable to a specific type/class, this is done so in `TicketManager1 implements TicketManager<ChildTicket1>`, it essentially "replaces" all the `T`s in the interface with `ChildTicket1`. See this wikipedia article for further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Generic_class_definitions